# Pixelmator's Pixel Tool Not Available

Tags: software, pixelmator

This is probably a really stupid question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. I want to use the pixel tool in Pixelmator, but I can't find it. Below is a picture of my toolbar. Is there something I'm missing?

[image: My Pixelmator Toolbar]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Pixel Tool in Pixelmator]

You need to manually add the **Pixel Tool** to the Tools palette first.

> You can add it there manually by choosing **Pixelmator > Preferences > Tools > Painting**. Then simply drag it onto the Tools palette to place it there.

Source: http://support.pixelmator.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10260

Comment: What an absolutely crazy UI. How is the Red Eye tool default and not the Pencil tool?

Comment: I created an account just to upvote this. I feel stupid now. Thanks!